# Orchard Core Razor Tag Helper unexpected redirection

Tags: razor, razor-pages, orchardcms

I'm building a decoupled CMS site using Orchard Core. I have a strange issue where `asp-page`  tag helper redirects me to a URL path on the admin panel. Example:

```
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
```

redirects to

```
https://localhost:7181/Admin/OrchardCore.Settings/Admin/Index?page=%2FPrivacy
```

I might have accidentally messed up something in the Orchard configuration, I've been playing with it a lot, but now I cannot quite make it behave as expected.

Comment: update: I started fresh and repeated all the steps from the documentation: https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/latest/docs/guides/decoupled-cms/
The same problem arises right 'out of the box' after the website setup.

Comment: By just adding Orchard to your project, you're asking it to add a bunch of default routes so that doesn't seem too strange. Why aren't you specifying the area though? That should be the name of your module.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Yes, I already figured out the thing about the areas. I couldn't find any info on it in the documentation tho. Problem solved!

Comment: Cool, glad that worked. Posting it as an answer for future folks having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the 'asp-area' attribute to be the name of your module.